# How can I do a 301 for URLS containing a certain word?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I'm not good with Regex at all so bear with me.

I want to do a 301 redirect for the following:

```
http://{mydomain.com}/searches/{whatever}?{whatever}={whatever} => http://mynewdomain.com/
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: @sputnick Asking about regex makes this a good Q/A site to use. Now whether this is the best way to do a redirect is another issue altogether...

Comment: So you just want to redirect to the root of the new domain? Do you not care about what was searched for?

Answer (score 0):

add these directives to .htaccess in the mydomain.com root directory (or virtual host config),
i assumed the length of whatever > 0

```
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+=.+$
 RewriteRule ^searches/.+$ http://mynewdomain.com/ [R=301,L,NC]
```